# How to set a variable inside closure using Swift 5 and use it outside closure

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set a variable inside a closure using Swift. I wanna then retrieve the value outside the closure for further processing. I can't seem to do that. Is there any way I can do that? I have tried the code below. I have commented the part where I actually want the actions to be carried out.

```
class AttendanceDetailTVC: UITableViewController {

    var TPNumber = ""
    var Module = ""
    var AID = ""
    var intake = ""

    @IBOutlet var tblDetail: UITableView!

    var detailList = [DetailModel]()


    var ref = Database.database().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tblDetail.delegate = self
        tblDetail.dataSource = self

        ref.child("Student").child(TPNumber).child("Intake").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            self.intake = (snapshot.value as? String)!
            self.detailList.removeAll()
        })
        ref.child("Record").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let value = child.key

                self.ref.child("Attendance").child(value).child("Intake").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    for child1 in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                        let value1 = child1.key

                        self.ref.child("Attendance").child(value).child("Intake").child(value1).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                            if let value2 = snapshot.value as? String {
                                if (self.intake == value2) {
                                    self.AID = value //This is where I set the value
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
            let det = DetailModel(AID: self.AID as String?) //This is where I want to use the value
            self.detailList.append(det)

            self.tblDetail.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code where you are declaring the variable? That would need to be done at the class level, outside the closure.

Comment: @GntlmnBndt yes, that is indeed being done at the class level. Outside this method.

Comment: Can you show that code? Can you also describe the actual behavior vs expected? Are you getting an error of any kind?

Comment: @GntlmnBndtI have edited the post with the full code including where I declare variables.

Comment: The answer provided by @excitedmicrobe is correct. There are a number of additional issues with this code. To clarify; the code inside the function `ref.child("Student")` could be called *after* the code inside `ref.child("Record")` and that would cause `if (self.intake` in the second function to be nil, causing a crash. Firebase is asynchronous and you have to work on returned objects within the closure following the call. Outside of that it may be nil. Additionally, there are two nested called to the same node - while technically not wrong, you're hitting Firebase twice for no reason.

Comment: We could probably help but would need to see a snippet of your Firebase structure to understand what's going on. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a *snippet* of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 3):

You're executing this function all at once, without waiting to actually retrieve the data first:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tblDetail.delegate = self
    tblDetail.dataSource = self
    ref.child("Record").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let value = child.key

            self.ref.child("Attendance").child(value).child("Intake").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for child1 in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let value1 = child1.key

                    self.ref.child("Attendance").child(value).child("Intake").child(value1).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        if let value2 = snapshot.value as? String {
                            if (self.intake == value2) {
                                self.AID = value //This is where I set the value
                                self.reloadTable()
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
func reloadTable() {
    let det = DetailModel(AID: self.AID) //This is where I wanna retrieve the value
    self.detailList.append(det)
    self.tblDetail.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I get an error with this. "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'"

Comment: @MuhammadHasanKhan fixed

Comment: This is the right answer. BUT - there's a lot of redundancy here that could be eliminated to make it much cleaner code. This code `self.ref.child("Attendance").child(value).child("Intake").observe(.value` reads in the */Attendence/value/Intake* node which *includes all child data* but then you're hitting the database again `self.ref.child("Attendance").child(value).child("Intake")` to read the data you've already read. That second read could be eliminated and just get the child data data you want from the first read.

Comment: @Jay Maybe you can correct him by editing this answer? Or writing an answer. Contributions are welcome :)